# Unable to run Maintenance after starting a new activity with the join button

Tags: java, android, okhttp

1. Here is my code in main activity,

   ```
   btn_req.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(View v) {
           Intent incident = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SensorReceive.class);
           startActivity(incident);
       }
   });
   ```
2. I use code above Intent this:

   ```
   public class SensorReceive extends Activity{
       private static final String TAG = "SensorReceive";
       public void getSync(View view) {
           OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
           new Thread() {
               @Override
               public void run() {
                   Request request = new Request.Builder()
                           .url("https://www.httpbin.org/get?key=0&answer=1")
                           .build();
                   Call call = client.newCall(request);
                   try {
                       Response response = call.execute();
                       Log.i(TAG, "getMessage:" + response.body().string());
                   } catch (IOException e) {
                       e.printStackTrace();
                   }
               }
           }.start();
       }
   ```
3. Error

   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7JKRf.png)

If anyone has encountered a similar situation, please let me know the reason.